BigQuery won't recognize paired double quotes in CSV
I have a .CSV file I am pulling data from in Google Cloud Storage into a BigQuery external table with the following text: ASR-184,05/15/2023,""Occurence"" is spelled incorrectly on the ticket summaries,Please update the spelling from ‘Occurance’ to ‘Occurrence’,Closed,
I am having issues with BigQuery not recognizing the pair of double quotes here as a literal. It appears to interpret the ""Occurence"" part as being a column and is giving me an error because it is expecting a comma afterwards presumably.
How can I fix this? I have very limited control over what the .CSV extracts I am receiving look like unfortunately, and it works if I add a pair of quotation marks around that column like so: ASR-184,05/15/2023,"""Occurence"" is spelled incorrectly on the ticket summaries",Please update the spelling from ‘Occurance’ to ‘Occurrence’,Closed,. Is this solely a result of how BQ parses CSV data? From what I understand the pairs of double quotes is the correct way to escape quote characters as per the ISO .CSV standard.
